# Como cambiar los elementos de posiciones en un array, que el primer elemento en la posicion 0 vaya a la ultima y el ultima a la primera, y asi

Tags: java

Hasta el momento llevo este codigo, pero al imprimir el vector salen 56 elementos cuando tienen que salir 8, los primeros 6 salen bien pero despues de eso se repite el numero 10, no entiendo por que, la funcion del algoritmo es cambiar el elemento en la primera posicion que vaya a la ultima posicion y el de la ultima posicion a la primera, el segundo elemento a la penultima posicion, y el el elemento en esa posicion que pase a la 2da posicion y asi, hasta recorrer todo el vector:

solo llevo este codigo con el error que mencione al principio:

```
public class TemperaturaVector {
public static void main(String[] args){
   
   
    try{


       int temp [] = new int[]{35, 10, 42, -15, 20, 8, -20, 25};


        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length-1; i++) {
            for (int j = temp.length-1; j >=0 ; j--) {
                temp[i]=temp[j];
                temp[j]=temp[i];
                System.out.print(temp[i]+"|");
                
            }
            
        }
         }
          catch (Exception error) {
           System.out.println("Se presentó un error \n" + error);
         }
          finally{
           System.out.println("Fin del programa");           
         }
      } 

   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si entiendo bien... teniendo este array de elementos

```
int[] temp = {35, 10, 42, -15, 20, 8, -20, 25};
```

Hay que cambiar 35 con 25, 10 con -20, 42 con 8, -15 con 20, hasta que quede este el array de esta manera:

```
int[] temp = {25, -20, 8, 20, -15, 42, 10, 35};
```

Esto se podría realizar usando un bucle for, con 2 variables llamadas `left` and `right` para ser mas claros

```
for (int left = 0, right = temp.length-1; left < right; left++, right--) {
    int aux = temp[left];
        
    temp[left] = temp[right];
    temp[right] = aux;
}
```

Si imprimís el array al final te debería quedar así

```
25, -20, 8, 20, -15, 42, 10, 35
```

Comment: Si men funciona, muchas gracias bro, no sabia de esos metodos left  y right

Comment: @Sebastian no son métodos, son los nombres que le dio a sus variable, tú puedes poner cualquier nombre a tu variable pero siempre se recomienda que sea algún nombre que guarda relación con el valor que va almacenar